# Pandoc - HTML to Markdown - How to change the style of bullet lists?

Tags: markdown, pandoc

Is there an option or extension in pandoc to represent bullet lists using the Asterisk character (*) instead of the Hyphen/Minus character (-) when converting from HTML to markdown?

The current output:

```
-   item 1
-   item 2
-   item 3
```

The desired output:

```
* item 1
* item 2
* item 3
```